# <textarea> not properly POSTING information

Tags: php, html, textarea

here is the code:

```
echo '<form id="register" action="index.php" method="post">
       <textarea form="register" name="mloc"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="continue" name="submit>"
       </form>';
```

on index.php:

```
$a=$_POST['mloc'];
```

this returns:

> NOTICE: undefined index `mloc` on line 1

Comment: Do you get that error only when the page loads or also when the form is submitted?

Comment: Did you output `$_POST` on the `index` page? Does the form show `mloc` as submitting?

Comment: You don't need `form="register"` when textarea is inside the form.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour well, that solved it. but why would it break it in the first place??

Comment: It was just a tip! Do you have another form with same ID in that page?

Comment: Nope. That... fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `form="register"` when textarea is inside the form. So:

```
echo '<form id="register" action="index.php" method="post">
       <textarea name="mloc"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="continue" name="submit>"
       </form>';
```